# Copying Start Screen to all users, including uninstallation

Tags: windows-8.1, sysprep

I have lots of the shiny <strike>new</strike> Microsoft Surface Pro tablets that I'm to set up, and distribute to my staff. One of the Group Policies I have to enforce is to disable all use of the Microsoft Store, and therefore, some apps that rely on the Microsoft Account. I set up the default user, and copied its profile over. I then also copied the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms` file into the Default user's profile folder, so the tile customizations are copied over.

However, the problem is that new users will see a lot of the default Windows 8 Modern UI programs appear that they won't be able to access (since they will be blocked from using Microsoft Accounts). They appear, and some are quite big, and it messes with my layout for them. **How can I remove those extra Modern UI applications from all users, so the `appsFolder.itemdata-ms` file takes over?**

Answer (score 1):

The TechNet article '[Customize the Start Screen](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134269.aspx#BKMK_AppFolder)' has a section titled 'Copy the AppsFolderLayout.Bin file to set default Start screen layout' that should help you setup your default Start screen layout the way you want it.

You may also want to watch the [Windows 8.1 Deployment Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-8-1-deployment-jump-start) from the Microsoft Virtual Academy, there is a lot of good information to help you with deploying Windows 8.1.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using MDT and SCM to build a local group policy and then using MDT to build the image for you and apply the GPOs dynamically at deploy time.

It would work something like this,

Install MDT 2013 and ADK

Build a share for booting images, in this share, import the .wim from the Win8 ISO. Create a Task Sequence for building your image. This TS will have office and dot net, the basic stuff.

Build your reference image in a VM. You do this by adding a suspend task to the build task sequence, booting the VM to boot.iso from this share and telling MDT to capture when done.

Create a GPO pack in SCM and save it to your share.

http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Research/tabid/62/EntryId/47/Creating-and-Applying-Custom-GPO-Packs-using-MDT-2012-Beta-2-with-or-without-SCCM-2007-2012.aspx

Import the image you built into a second share you use for pushing images to PCs, in this share you would add drivers and most applications like flash and adobe. This share would then apply any and all GPOs you built in SCM.

You then boot PCs into this share's boot.iso from CD/USB/PXE, whatever.

SEE:

http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Videos/MDT2010LiteTouchUnleashedVideos.aspx